# Почему не работает функция для получения значения ключей, getKeys?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Есть массивы объектов: *posts*, *albums*. Есть функция **getPost()** которая возвращает в результат значение определенных ключей, определенных юзеров.
 Есть функция **getKey()** которая в теории дает возможность возвращать значения ключей новых массивов,без повторения кода. Если раскомментировать вызов **//getPhotos(1)** тогда функция **getKey()** не сработает, **вопрос почему?**

```js
let posts = [
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
},
{
"userId": 2,
"id": 11,
"title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem",
"body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qui neque voluptates ut commodi qui incidunt\nut animi commodi"
},
{
"userId": 3,
"id": 22,
"title": "dolor sint quo a velit explicabo quia nam",
"body": "eos qui et ipsum ipsam suscipit aut\nsed omnis non odio\nexpedita earum mollitia molestiae aut atque rem suscipit\nnam impedit esse"
}]
let albums = [
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "quidem molestiae enim"
},
{
"userId": 2,
"id": 11,
"title": "quam nostrum impedit mollitia quod et dolor"
},
 {
"userId": 3,
"id": 22,
"title": "et rem non provident vel ut"
}]
let state = {
posts: [],
albums: []
}; 

function getPost(userId) {
 let post = posts.reduce(function(acc, item) {
 if(item.userId === userId) {
  acc.push(item['title'])
 }
  return acc;
 }, [])

state.posts = post
return state.posts
}

function getKey(le, arr, get, key) { 
var le = arr.reduce(function(acc,item) {
 if(item.get === get) {
  acc.push(item[key])
 }
 return acc;
},[])

state.arr = le
return state.arr
}

function getPhotos(albumId) {


  getKey(p, photos, albumId, "url"); // вызываю функцию с нужными параметрами

} 

getPost(1) // вызывает пост userId = 1
//getPhotos(1) // не вызывается
console.log(state)
```

Comment: где объявлена переменная `p`, которая используется в вызове `getKey(p, photos, albumId, "url"); // вызываю функцию с нужными параметрами`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде очень много воды, поэтому я постараюсь тебе помочь реализовать то, что ты хотел, не отвечая на твой вопрос:

1. Есть функция `getPost`, которая по `userId` должна получать пост, тогда я не понимаю, зачем ты изменяешь `state`? Функция с префиксом `get` в названии явно ничего не должна менять.

   ```
   function getPostByUserId(array, userId) {
     return array.find(post => post.userId == userId)
   }
   ```

   так код намного короче и понятнее.
2. Вторая функция `getKey` не отражает того, что она действительно делает на самом деле, в твоем случае логичнее ее назвать `getItemByKey`, ее реализация примет следующий вид

   ```
   getItemByKeyValue(array, key, value) {
     return array.find(item => item[key] === value);
   }
   ```

   Функция вернет тебе нужный объект по заданному ключу с определенным значением.

Если ты перепишешь свой код с использованием этих подходов, то я думаю, что твоя проблема решится. А вообще, когда работаешь со `state` в любой абстракции, то его нельзя менять на прямую, это плохая практика. `State` обычно изменяется путем присваивания нового `state`.

Comment: CoonJs, спасибо, а потом в вашем способе надо присваивать значение функции отдельно куда захочется.

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович именно) Старайтесь писать код именно таким образом, и тогда не будет никаких проблем)